# 'undefined' returned from .each ran on tr with id selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, each

**Problem**

I'm trying to run through every row in a table that has an id in a particular format. The correct number of rows are being selected but I'm encountering an **'undefined'** issue whenever I try to get attributes from the obj.

```
<tr class="" data-uid="45" id="fixed_user_45">...
```

And the javascript...

```
$('tr[id^="fixed_user_"] ').each(function(obj, i) {

var id = $(obj).id; // returns 'undefined'
console.log(id); //prints 'undefined' the correct number of times

});
```

This is happening regardless of the attribute I try to select, and how I go about it - i.e. innerText, innerHTML, .attr('data-uid'). All are undefined.

---

**Other Details:**

For completeness... I'm going to cycle through each of the td after so have nested the following within the above each function.

```
$('td').each(function (obj, i) {
```

---

**Thanks all for your help.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the javascript snippet you got the parameters order wrong

```
.each(function(obj, i) {
```

The correct order is

```
.each(function(i, obj) {
```

Then you have to call jQuery `.attr()` function to get the id.

```
$(obj).attr('id')
```

However you can get no parameters (if you don't need index) and use `this` as current object.

```
$(this).attr('id');
```

To see it working go the this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zv6guhzn/1/
If you want to cycle through nested td I suggest to use `.find()` that is faster than general selector `$()` because it search nested elements starting from selected.

```
$(obj).find('td').each(itd, objtd){
    console.log( $(objtd).text() );
}
```

full example with nested loops https://jsfiddle.net/zv6guhzn/2/

source https://api.jquery.com/each/#example-2

Answer (score 0):

`obj` is the index and `i` is the element for your case. To get `data-uid` use `data()` function like below.

```
$('tr[id^="fixed_user_"] ').each(function (obj, i) {
     var id = $(i).data('uid'); 
     console.log(id); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

each method:

```
$(array/object).each(function(index,object){});
```

Code:

```
$('tr[id^="fixed_user_"] ').each(function(i, obj) {

var id = obj.id; // returns 'undefined'
console.log(id); //prints 'undefined' the correct number of times

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to JQuery `each` method:

> .each( function )
>  
>   **function** Type: Function( Integer index, Element element ) A function
>   to execute for each matched element.

```
$('tr[id^="fixed_user_"]').each(function(index, obj) {

    var id = $(obj).data('uid);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use following code to get required results.

```
$('tr[id^="fixed_user_"] ').each(function() {

  console.log($(this).attr('id'));  //return each id
  console.log($(this).attr('data-uid'));// returns 'data-uid'
  console.log($(this).data('uid'));// also returns 'data-uid'

});
```